# catch() on angularjs $http.get() call doesn't suppress error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, angular-promise

I have the following code (simplified and [running in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOveqe) for the sake of example):

```
var app = angular.module("httptest", []);

app.controller("getjson", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEwdw.js").
  then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log('in then')
    throw 'the error'
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log('in the catch')
    console.log(e);
  });
}]);
```

My expectation here is that, if the `catch()` block is entered, the error will not show up in the console, except where logged explicitly (i.e., it will not show up in red). However, this is not the case, red error message prints to the console, and then the `catch()` block is entered. I tried to set up [an equivalent example here](https://jsfiddle.net/rj3dhL4m/) that does not use AngularJS's `$http`, and it behaves the way I expect:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve();
});

promise1.then((result) => {
  console.log('about to throw error')
  throw 'hey'
 }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

In this example, no red error makes it through.

What is going on here, and is it possible to suppress the handled error in the `$http` case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior was fixed with the release of AngularJS 1.6:

From GitHub commits:

> ### fix($q): treat thrown errors as regular rejections
>
> Previously, errors thrown in a promise's `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` handlers were treated in a
>   slightly different manner than regular rejections:
>   They were passed to the `$exceptionHandler()` (in addition to being converted to rejections).
>
> — [AngularJS GitHub Commit e12eea](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e13eeabd7e34a78becec06cfbe72c23f2dcb85f9)

See also [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-q-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find explanation at line 8416 in your linked angularjs module. They simply console.error in catch statement. You can override this behaviour, f.e. by empty handler:

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', () => (exception, cause) });

var app = angular.module("httptest", ['exceptionOverride']);

....
```